# How to get direct path using Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I want to write simple Batch file will click on the batch file
 I should go to my directory path should be D:\DS\Install

At present i am doing every 1hr go to 
 RUN command and typing to cmd and connect to D:\DS\Install
 Instead of this I want short cut option.. :-)

Comment: Please be very clear about what you are trying to do. You have two batch files and you want to invoke one from the other?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

You want a shortcut on desktop which will open a command prompt and change directory to D:\DS\Install

This is pretty straight forward:

1. Go to C:\windows\system32 and copy cmd.exe to D:\DS\Install folder
2. Now right click on the cmd.exe in D:\DS\Install folder and send it to desktop create shortcut.

You will have a shortcut on desktop which will take you to the required folder everytime..

Just FYI... cmd.exe will always open from the directory where it is placed.

Comment: this for cmd prompt quick

Answer (score 0):

Just create a shortcut in your desktop, and when asked for the location, type this command

```
cmd.exe /k "cd /d "d:\ds\install""
```

This shortcut will call `cmd` to execute the `cd` to change the drive/folder and keep the window open to continue working with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a batch file called `ds.bat` and put it in `c:\windows` or any other folder that is on the path.

You can then use the WIN+R hotkey and type `ds` and enter.

```
@echo off
cd /d "d:\ds\install"
cmd /k
```

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
cd /d "d:\ds\install"
cmd /k

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.